# BEX error in Windows Vista in hearts.exe

Tags: windows-vista, crash

I have got an error in Windows Vista and my games are not playing. What should I do?

```
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: Hearts.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.6002.18005
  Application Timestamp:    49e01e10
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_fd00
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Offset: 0253a350
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: fd00
  Additional Information 2: ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
  Additional Information 3: fd00
  Additional Information 4: ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
```

Answer (score 1):

BEX means Buffer overflow EXception. This is a term only a programmer could love and understand, but basically it means the program tried to put something into memory it isn't allowed to use. If you were writing a program this could be due to a bug in your code. Since it's happening in Hearts.exe and other games, I suspect you have a virus. Windows is preventing it from doing something (good) but it means you can't run your games and it may be causing real problems elsewhere.

Make sure you have a virus scanner. If you don't there are some free ones available.

Make sure your virus scanner is up to date. If your subscription has expired, renew it.

Run a full virus scan and correct all the problems it finds.